# Best way in Python to combine 2 lists and return a min / max of a set

Tags: python, list, tuples

I currently have two set lists that combine "steps" and "time":

```
step = 1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2
time = 1,2,5,6,1,3,5,6
```

These values directly correlate, meaning a tuple looking like [(1,1),(1,2),(1,5),(1,6),(2,1),(2,3),(2,5),(2,11)]

Basically I'm trying to find the max value for step 1, and the min value of step one, as well as min/max for step 2

```
minstep1 = 1
maxstep1 = 6
minstep2 = 1
maxstep2 = 11
```

how can I accomplish this in python? do i need to create a multidimensional list?  is there a function that can iterate keyvalue pairs of a tuple that I can just use the zip function?

Thanks!

Comment: Where did you get the `(2,11)` from?

Comment: Are there always two steps, or is their number variable?

Comment: the 2,11 was a misstype, this case it'd be 2,6, I meant to have it be 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). Here is some example code for your question:

```
step = 1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2
time = 1,2,5,6,1,3,5,6

from itertools import groupby, izip
from operator import itemgetter

for key, group in groupby(izip(step, time), itemgetter(0)):
    group = [item[1] for item in group]
    print 'Step:', key, 'Min:', min(group), 'Max:', max(group)
```

It groups `time` by `step` then finds the `min` and `max` for each group. Alternatively, you could do something like:

```
step.reverse()
for key, group in groupby(time, lambda _: step.pop()):
    group = tuple(group)
    print 'Step:', key, 'Min:', min(group), 'Max:', max(group)
```

To group by `step` without `zip`ping with `time`.

Comment: What happens if step and time are out of order? if I have 1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2

Comment: Then do `sorted(izip(step, time), key=itemgetter(0))` instead of `izip(step, time)`. `groupby` is implemented in `c` so can be faster than a reimplementation with `set` even if you have to sort first.

Comment: thanks, I'll do some testing on both solutions, both function as I'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach?

```
step = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2]
time = [1,2,5,6,1,3,5,6]

from collections import defaultdict
dd = defaultdict(set)

for s,t in zip(step, time):
    dd[s].add(t)

for k,v in dd.iteritems():
    print "step %d  min: %d max: %d" %(k, min(v), max(v))
```

Comment: Use `add` instead of `union`. Won't be as fast as the built in `groupby` since it takes advantage of `time` already being sorted by `step` (and is implemented in C in CPython).

Comment: this method actually seams to function when step are unordered

Comment: This solution also produces what I was after.

Comment: I'm going to have to run some `timeit`s to see if this is faster than `sorted` + `groupby` when `time` isn't sorted by `step`... it might be.